# Coordinates from UTM to Latitude and Longitude in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I have a DataFrame with the following result:
[image]

and I want to convert those coordinate columns from WGS84 to Lon & Lat and finally add those new columns in my data frame:

For conversion I am using the following code, but I think there should a better way without converting the coordinate columns to list and create a new one DataFrame.

```
import pyproj as pp
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import pandas as pd

cx =dfb.COORDENADA_X.tolist()
cy =dfb.COORDENADA_Y.tolist()

utm15_wgs84 = pp.Proj(init='epsg:32615')

for ix, iy in zip(cx, cy):
    lon, lat = utm15_wgs84(ix, iy, inverse=True)
    print(lon, lat)
```

Any suggestion for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `apply` function in `pandas` `DataFrame`. For example

```
dfb[['wgs_x', 'wgs_y']] = dfb.apply(lambda row:utm15_wgs84(row['COORDENADA_X'], row['COORDENADA_Y'], inverse=True), axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Hi warmoverflow, thanks for you reply...I am getting the following error message    555                     return inx,False,False,False
    556                 except:
--> 557                     raise TypeError('input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar')
    558     else:
    559         # perhaps they are regular python arrays?

TypeError: ('input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: There was an error in the code which I have fixed. Please try again.

Comment: You are welcome. Please up vote and accept this answer.

Comment: @hammu hi, this code is working for you? i am trying to use the same `EPSG` but its converting in bad way, even in Yours values, its showing me that you value ` 412595.19` is `-93.836697` any ideas?